# visual studio Apple App Store Connect API key key parameters not valid

Tags: .net, visual-studio, maui

In Visual Studio for Windows Community 2022 17.4.0 Preview 1.0 there is a new way of deploying a MAUI app to a local iOS device. Previously there was provisioning. Now Visual studio takes me through a setup for Hot Restart and when I choose individual developer account I am presented with request for Apple App Store Connect API Key information. I followed instructions to create these and when I enter them into the dialog box I get the below error and cannot go any further.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5fZu.png)

I have no clue what Q,X and Q,Y are or named curves or explicit curves.

Anyone else seen this before and got it to work?

Comment: You can first check that the values of these fields  are correct while setting for Hot Restart.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I have attempted several times to enter the values, both typing them in and copying direct from the webpage but always the same error. The values I am using from the API connect webpage are the Name which I put into the Name field in VS, the issuer ID that I copy from the issuer ID on apple webpage and Key ID which I also copy form apple webpage using the provided copy button Then for the "Private key path" field I click on 3 dots and select the p8 file I downloaded from apple API Key webpage. This p8 file has the filename "AuthKey_" followed by the Key Id value.

Comment: I just tried renaming the p8 file to the Key Id but same error

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT have you managed to get this to work?

Comment: You can check if it's invalid and then try to create a new one.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT Yes you were right! I revoked old one and created new key (but with developer access) and everything worked fine. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also was having issues where VS was not adding any apple accounts, individual or Enterprise.  I restarted VS in Admin mode and was able to add an enterprise and individual account without issue.  The trick for me was to run VS as admin .